# CRM 2011 filter connections lookup to exclude entities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We have a requirement to restrict the users from creating connections to contacts.

So I am looking for Jscript code to filter the record2id lookup of the connection entity to allow all entities except 'Contact'.

Is there a way we can acheive thsi using Jscript ?
[image]

Comment: Does it have to be JScript? You could do it in a supported fashion using plugins.

Comment: I thought doing it using Jscript would be simpler and is more like a prevention, rather than allowing the user to choose and throwing an error message at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this kind of scripting would be supported (would appreciate to see a supported script to do that) and sticking to supported solutions may be a good idea especially because of UR12 (the script to remove the contact from that list may work in IE but not in other browsers, therefore letting the user to create a connection to a contact). Furthermore, any user with a little more knowledge of Javascript and debugging would be able to bypass such script and still allow a connection to a contact to be created.

Have you considered an alternate solution such as a pre-validation plugin? You could validate the entity and throw an exception with a meaningful message to the user and that would work regardless of script / browser and would be fully supported.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you. It looks like plugin is the best approach then, and I'm going to use that.

Comment: @CrazyFrog If dimamura's reply answered your question, don't forget to check it as such. It's always a nice tickle to the ego to see the green birdy appear. :)